# CSS in Google Chrome browser - MAC

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to add css rule to the starting page in chrome browser on Mac.

I want to make column-count:5 instead of default column-count:5.

**How can I change Google Chrome front-page css file?**

That's the url;
view-source:chrome://new-tab-page/

[image: no code needed]

Answer (score -1):

Add "User CSS" extension to your Chrome from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb)